# RobotWebTools.org: using ros3djs with own URDF

Tags: ros, urdf, robot-state-publisher, robotwebtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,
I've tried to use RobotWebTools ros3djs with own created robot.urdf.
Is there a description, how to use it ?
What must be running at the server side ?
What must be changed at html file ?

I get the following erros, when trying to test my robot model:
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [4108]
[ERROR] [1369728743.307774572]: Could not find parameter robot_description on parameter server
[ERROR] [1369728743.307982455]: Could not generate robot model
[ERROR] [1369728743.308055194]: Failed to extract kdl tree from xml robot description
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 4108, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/ros/.ros/log/52bc6f94-c76e-11e2-a00d-00139508481b/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/ros/.ros/log/52bc6f94-c76e-11e2-a00d-00139508481b/robot_state_publisher-2*.log

I'm using the following launch file:

-->

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance

Cheers
Chrimo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63672/robotwebtools.org:-using-ros3djs-with-own-urdf/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've changed some parameters and all nodes startup without error messages now:

started roslaunch server http://ros:51535/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /robot_description
- /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
- /rosbridge/port
- /rosbridge_websocket/authenticate
- /rosdistro
- /rosversion
- /use_gui

NODES
/
robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
rosapi (rosapi/rosapi)
rosbridge_websocket (rosbridge_server/rosbridge_websocket)
tf2_web_republisher (tf2_web_republisher/tf2_web_republisher)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [5714]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 48110e0a-c77e-11e2-be9c-00139508481b
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [5727]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rosbridge_websocket-2]: started with pid [5739]
process[rosapi-3]: started with pid [5742]
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [5749]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1369735597.567725] Rosbridge WebSocket server started on port 9090
process[tf2_web_republisher-5]: started with pid [5781]

But when connecting to webserver, the robot will not be shown:

I use the following html code:

MockBot URDF







  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-39765480-1', 'robotwebtools.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');


  
  function init() {
    var ip = location.host;
    var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
      url : 'ws://'+ip+':9090'
    });

    var viewer = new ROS3D.Viewer({
      divID : 'urdf',
      width : window.innerWidth,
      height : window.innerHeight,
      background : '#efefef',
      antialias : true
    });
    viewer.addObject(new ROS3D.Grid());

    new ROS3D.UrdfClient({
      ros : ros,
      tfClient : new ROSLIB.TFClient({
        ros : ros,
        angularThres : 0.01,
        transThres : 0.01,
        rate : 10.0
      }),
      path : 'http://resources.robotwebtools.org/',
      rootObject : viewer.scene
    });
  }

Now my new questions:

1. what is the path at ROS3D.UrdfClient ?
   ...
   path : 'http://resources.robotwebtools.org/'
   ...
2. what is this ???

(function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o), m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-39765480-1', 'robotwebtools.org');
  ga('send', 'pageview');



Thanks for some more hints :-)

Cheers
Chrimo

BTW: you will find my last work at:
https://github.com/mockbot/MockBot.git




---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2013-05-28


This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, ros3djs only supports loading Collada meshes from the URDF. The path variable you see is the base URL where the mesh files are located. ros3djs will then attempt to load those files and display them (e.g., http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros3djs#Mesh_Resource_Hosting). Other URDF model types could be added, but are currently unsupported. A feature request could be made here: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/issues/

The `GoogleAnalyticsObject` code snippet you posted is for Google analytics tracking on the Robot Web Tools website. It has nothing to do with the demo. Instead of using the source code from that page, I would check out these:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ros3djs/Tutorials/VisualizingAURDF
https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/blob/stable/examples/urdf.html
http://robotwebtools.org/jsdoc/ros3djs/current/ROS3D.UrdfClient.html

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1